# Formula of Gauss' Law of Gravitation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

[Gauss's law for Gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity):

$$\int g\cdot \mathrm{d}S=4\pi GM$$

where $g$ is the gravitational field and $S$ is the surface area.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\oint_{\partial V} g\cdot dS=-4\pi GM_{enclosed}$ where integral is surface integral over a closed surface.

Comment: This is what the Wikipedia page has, but they write $dA$ instead of $dS$ and write a double closed integral.  I'm not a stickler about calculus grammar, but the symbology seems to be the central confusion of the question.